# Creating Domain Model

Tags: object, domain-driven-design, modeling

I have created a use case of a small application and now I have to create a Domain Model of that use cases of the application and which functions will be implemented in this application. I have no previous experience in Domain Modeling and UML, please suggest me steps to create the domain model or any suggestions, Do I have to have a very solid understanding of Object oriented concepts for creating domain model?
The application is simple and creates online poll/voting system and have functions like Register Account, Confirmation Email of account, Membership, Create Poll, Send Poll etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in UML the Domain Model is the Class Diagram, and to create a Class Diagram you have to have a firm understanding of object oriented programming, since you design the classes with their methods and properties. To get started, take the real world approach. Think "How does a poll work in real life?". For example, a poll needs a question like "Which one is the best star trek series?". So you have to create a property question on the class poll. Then you need methods, to add a vote, so this method could be AddVote()... etc. etc.

Read up on UML and OOP on wiki.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You surely need some knowledge or at least basics of object oriented design and analysis. There are many different ways you can create domain model in terms of objects from use cases. In the Unified Process methodology (which is created by authors of UML) you firstly detail use cases by creating use case realizations mostly by describing possible interactions using behavioural UML diagrams. Another way to do this is by the CRC (class responsibility cards) method. The simplest approach I herad of, but not so effective at the same time, is just after detailing use cases using textual description of the interactions declaring all found nouns, which are part of the system, as your classes and verbs as their methods.